# How to start a transaction in JPA using entityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have started working on an application which uses spring, hibernate, JPA, SOAP webservices. Now there is a requirement that certain queries have to be run in a transaction. If any one fails, entire transaction should rollback.

The code in the dao layer is as follows :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

    public class BillDAOImpl implements BillDao{

             @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
             private EntityManager em;

             public boolean processBills() throws Exception{

             EntityTransaction tx = null;
             Session session = null;

             try{

                 session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
                 tx = em.getTransaction();

                 Bill bill = em.find(Bill.class, billId);

                 //session.beginTransaction();
                 tx.begin();
                 ...
                 ...
                 em.persist(bill);
                 ...
                 ...
                 em.merge(<other object>);
                 ...
                 ...
                 //session.getTransaction().commit();
                 tx.commit();
             } catch(){
             }

             }

    }
```

When it executes `tx = em.getTransaction()`, it gives following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute getTransaction() on a container-managed EntityManager
```

The other transaction related properties are as follows :

```
<bean id="tuneEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/tune-persistence.xml"
        p:persistenceUnitName="tunePersistenceUnit" p:loadTimeWeaver-ref="loadTimeWeaver"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
        p:dataSource-ref="tuneDbDataSource">
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup
                </prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/${tune-db.ehcache.config.file}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</prop>              
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${tune-db.schema}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">${tune-db.schema}</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">${tune-db.data.validation}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${tune-db.hibernate.show-sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${tune-db.hibernate.format-sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>     
    </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="tuneEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

When I use `session.beginTransaction()` and `session.getTransaction().commit()`, it works correctly.

However I want to replace it with transaction from `entityManager`. Then what should be done?

Comment: Use the framework. You are working around the framework (both Spring and JPA). Instead use the frameworks (and maybe first do some reading on them instead).

Comment: related post: [How to manually start a transaction on a shared EntityManager in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26606608/8140473)

Answer (score 7):

Try injecting EntityManagerFactory and then creating the EntityManager manually:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public boolean processBills() throws Exception{

   EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

   EntityTransaction tx = null;

   Session session = null;

   try{

       session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
       tx = em.getTransaction();
```

Comment: The hard job to use Jpa EntityManager is to design code on "Process" to manage Transaction and closing the resources what jboss doc recommand

Answer (score 4):

The EntityManager instance returned by @PersistenceContext is always a container managed EntityManager. And container managed EntityManager are always JTA EntityManagers and hence their lifecycle is managed by the container. I guess now it makes sense as to why it is illegal to call getTransaction() on them.[This might help](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html)

Comment: Ok. I got this point. But session.beginTransaction() and session.commit() works. How does hibernate session object work?

Comment: I doubt that it is working because I implemented your code I am getting Transaction already active excption.

Answer (score 0):

The add a `hibernate.jta.allowTransactionAccess` property with the value `true` and you should be allowed to use it manually. Though it's not a good practice to mix your strategies, having some code managed by JTA, some manually.

Answer (score -2):

@Transactional annotation will do exactly what you need.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: actually I am not using @Transactional because in the code, we are calling a stored procedure, which throws exception, when tried to run within a transaction. So I do session.beginTransaction() and session.getTransaction().commit()  for the queries before the stored procedure call and then after the stored procedure call, again do the session.beginTransaction() and session.getTransaction().commit() .

Comment: What kind of exception do you get when you use @Transactional?

Comment: Then fix that issue instead of hacking around. You now have the issue that you have 2 transactions and that ou cannot rollback the first part... You are loosing ACID properties with this hack of yours...

Comment: If I use @Transactional, will it be container-manager transaction or application managed transaction? Also, entityManager should be directly injected or entitymanagerfactory should be injected and entityManager should be obtained from it?

Comment: @Transactional is going to be an application managed transaction. What do you mean by container-manager transaction? I am unclear about how the entityManager should be injected. I use spring-data-jpa and that wouldn't need you to access entityManager unless you need to define your own custom queries. And when I define my custom repositories  (and queries inside that), spring calls the constructor with EntityManager as a param and I use that.